# Configuring cpp sources in gradle

Tags: c++, build-automation, gradle

I have set up a project on top of Qt (so source is written in C++) and I wanted to try Gradle for automatic builds on that. It took me some time to get into the details of configuring a multi project build (there is an executable and two libs) and now I am trying to tell the `cpp-exe` and the `cpp-lib` plugin how my source tree is structured.

I have set up a task that should print all of the source sets (there should be at least the default ones right?) and it looks like this:

```
task projectinfo {
description = "Informations about the current project"
group = INFORMATIONS_GROUP

doFirst {
    task -> print ("""${task.project.sourceSets.all}""")
}
```

If I run this task Gradle tells me that there is no property "sourceSets" for the project. [The documentation of the plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/cpp.html#N147EC) tells me that it is possible to customize the source locations, but not how.

So my question would be: How can I tell the Gradle `cpp` plugin which source files to use. If there is any documentation about the `cpp` plugin apart from its API documentation and the Gradle user guide that would be helping too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at [Adam Murdoch's usage](https://github.com/adammurdoch/native-platform) of Gradle's ['cpp plugin'](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/cpp.html). I believe he's one of the main Gradle submitters, so he should know how to use this better than anyone:

Exert from [native-platform/build.gradle](https://github.com/adammurdoch/native-platform/blob/master/build.gradle)

```
cpp {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            source.exclude 'curses.cpp'
        }
        curses {
            source.srcDirs = ['src/main/cpp']
            source.include 'curses.cpp'
            source.include 'generic.cpp'
            source.include 'generic_posix.cpp'
        }
    }
}

Then, within the 'libraries' node, refer to all/any combination of architecture and source sets:

sourceSets << cpp.sourceSets.main
sourceSets << cpp.sourceSets.curses
```

I've not had too long to look over it myself, but it looks like he defines a number of OS architecture based source code include combinations and stores these in the **variants** variable. He then processes them into platform JARs (I haven't actually ran the build yet, maybe I should).

Also, take a look at https://github.com/rklaren/GradleJNI, it uses the [cpp plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/cpp.html) but looks to be a little Windows-oriented.

**Update** - I also found https://github.com/alkemist/gradle-cpp-demo, which has an example of the 'cpp-exe' plugin building an executable.